# Monit - how to check loadavg only when no backup is running?

Tags: backup, monit, monitoring

I've got Monit configuration with:

```
check system example.com
    if loadavg (1min) > 4 then alert
    if loadavg (5min) > 2 then alert
```

I want to get rid of messages every time backup is running at night, but I do not want to turn it off completely.

How to add check for gzip/bzip2 process runing like:

```
`ps aux | grep '\[gb\]zip'`
```

or disable that one check at some time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell Monit to stop monitoring during certain times (ie while your backup is running). It uses the same syntax as cron. There are good examples in Monit Documentation in the [Service Poll Times](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#service_poll_time) section. You probably want something like:

```
check system example.com
not every "* 2-4 * * *"
```

This will stop monitoring every night from 2am-4am

Comment: `Error: syntax error 'not'`. Any ideas?

Comment: working with last version monit (I've got stable Debian with slightly older one)

Answer (score 2):

You should "unmonitor" the system load check during the backup interval.

`monit unmonitor example.com`

You can do this for a specific duration with an `at` script or just cron, if you know your backup window time.

Resume the monitoring after the backup window:

`monit monitor example.com`

Comment: That sounds good but I've got problem with it (root, shell): # monit unmonitor example.com
monit: action failed -- You are <b>not</b> authorized to access <i>monit</i>. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to sup

Comment: What's the output of `monit status` ?

Comment: monit: cannot read status from the monit daemon. Monit listens on 0 0.0.0.0:2812 and is not blocked on firewall or anything

Comment: status, unmonitor etc. are "Optional action arguments for non-daemon mode", but my monit runs as daemon

Answer (score 1):

Stop monit when run backup.

Like:

```
  ==backup.sh==
  /usr/local/etc/rc.d/monit stop
  ...do backup...
  /usr/local/etc/rc.d/monit start
```

Comment: that replace one problem with another: http://serverfault.com/questions/253263/how-to-disable-monit-instance-start-stop-alerts

Comment: it works with `set alert admin@example.com but not on { instance }`