# Suppress Monit message 'Monit instance changed' on stop/start

Tags: monit

I have monit installed on some user laptops/desktop so it can make sure a couple processes are always running/get restarted as needed.  But since the devices are regularly shutdown/restarted I frequently receive a message like below which I do not want or care about, since they are telling me that the system was restarted.  I want to suppress the messages that seem to automatically happen when monit starts/stops.

```
Subject: monit alert -- Monit instance changed

Service     - system_slaveone
Event       - Monit instance changed
Action      - start
Date        - Thu, 18 Apr 2013 07:53:51
Host        - slaveone.example.local (slaveone)
Description - Monit started.
```

But once the system is up, I do want to get some alerts about a couple services/resources that I do want to be notified about, so simply disabling email isn't want I want to do.

How can I suppress the message on startup/restart without completely disabling email?

Comment: Desirable feature on a server. Not so much on a workstation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, sure...

To suppress Monit alerts for a particular check, you need to use the **noalert** directive.

For instance, I can have a check for the cron daemon, which restarts weekly. Maybe I don't want that email in my inbox every Sunday...

```
check process cron
    noalert zoredache@mdmarra.net
    with pidfile "/var/run/crond.pid"
    start program = "/sbin/service crond start"
    stop program = "/sbin/service crond stop"
```

This works for any Monit check, so to handle the instance alarms for the system, you can suppress by adding the **noalert** under the `check system localhost` entry:

```
  check system localhost
    noalert zoredache@mdmarra.net
```

Try it. This still leaves any real services/daemons under Monit protection, but reduces the chatter. Great for misbehaving applications...

```
check process nslcd
        with pidfile "/var/run/nslcd/nslcd.pid" every 2 cycles
        noalert ewwhite@bra**ers.com
        start program = "/sbin/service nslcd start"
        stop program = "/sbin/service nslcd stop"
        if 10 restarts within 11 cycles then timeout
        if cpu usage > 95% for 11 cycles then restart
        if totalmemory > 128 MB then restart
```

Comment: Applying the alert configuration to the `check system localhost` is what I was looking for. I must have missed that in the man page.

Comment: It's not well documented. I had to experiment on my own 6 months ago to find it. Bummer is that you have to specify the exact mail addresses to be excluded.

Comment: But won't that disable all cron alerts, not just the expected weekly restart?

Comment: @Johan Nope....

Comment: How does monit know the noalert only applies to the weekly restart, not an unexpected problem during the week?  What've I missed?

Answer (score 8):

To particularly filter out the e-mails when monit starts/stops, you can use the `instance` event filter:

```
set alert myaddress@foo.bar not on { instance }
```

As in the [documentation](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Setting-an-event-filter):

```
Event:     | Failure state:            | Success state:              
---------------------------------------------------------------------
...
INSTANCE   | "Monit instance changed"  | "Monit instance changed not"
...
```