# How to suppress monit alert if restart successful?

Tags: monit

We only want to be alerted if the service *fails* to restart.  Is this possible?

That is if, on the first check the service is down then restart it and don't bother to send us an alert; but if the service is still down after two cycles then we want to know.

Tried `if not exist for 2 cycles then alert` but found that whilst we'd get an alert it would not try to restart.

So then tried the below but same result: sends an alert without attempting a restart.

```
check process mysql with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
   start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
   if not exist then restart
   if not exist for 2 cycles then alert
```

Can we set it to only send the alert when pain persists?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the Monit mailing list for specifics, or see if you can rework the logic to get the right effect. See my answer here for use of the `noalert` directive:

[Suppress Monit message 'Monit instance changed' on stop/start](https://serverfault.com/questions/500700/suppress-monit-message-monit-instance-changed-on-stop-start)

You may be able to add `noalert specific@mailaddress.com` under the action or check that you're trying to suppress.