# How to get monit to only alert once when a check fails, not when it comes back successful?

Tags: monit

Apologies if this is the same question as [How to suppress monit alert if restart successful?](https://serverfault.com/questions/593304/how-to-suppress-monit-alert-if-restart-successful), but it appears like it might be different, so I'm asking again..

We want to have a monit alert check when an instance's uptime is 2 minutes.  This is to alert us when an instance has rebooted.  I got it working with this:

`check program uptimecheck with path /root/uptime_check.sh
   if status != 0 then alert`

..but the problem is it also alerts when the "check succeeded".. I only want the alert when it fails.  How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain that you need a check to see if a server is rebooting?

Comment: does sound like a bad check. You should be monitoring the service it provides. If at some point you cluster this service so a reboot does not equal an outage you'll get someone out of bed for nothing.